# Remote Desktop Services Collections not showing for admin user in Server Manager

Tags: windows-server-2016, remote-desktop-services

I have created an new admin account and would like for that account to be able to view the remote desktop services overview and collections.

However the account cannot see any of the collections. Collections are not even there.

The domain admin can see everything normally of course. So I imagine this must be some sort of permission issue. But for the life of me I can't find the permission.

Answer (score 0):

It was not a permissions issue.

In looking at the server manager there was a message that a server was missing.

After I added that particular server to be monitored in the server manager. The collections showed up.

So for every new admin they will have to add the particular server in the server manager that is missing in order for collections to show up.